# How do I list files between two time stamps in a certain directory? (SunOS)

Tags: linux, list, unix, sunos

i.e.

List any files between 2014-01-25 1300 - 2014-01-25 2000 in

Cheers

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's Unix related and should better be asked on http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `find` command with multiple selectors - e.g. `find . -mtime +1 -mtime -3`.  It can be used with ctime, atime, etc., as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a GNU `find` (which you could compile on SunOS if you don't have it), use the [age range options for `find`](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Age-Ranges.html)